# PHP code for inserting data into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to set up a web page to manage my database. I have a table with 15 rows and I'm trying to write a script to insert data into a MySQL database via a form which has a dropdown menu. I keep getting this error:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Staff Database Update Form</title>
<style type="text/css">
.arial {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
}
.arial {
    font-size: 9px;
}
.arial1 {
    font-size: 9px;
}
.ARIALBOLD {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
.A1 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.A9 {
    font-size: 9px;
}
.Centre {
}
</style>
</head>

<body class="Centre">
<span class="ARIALBOLD">STAFF INFORMATION</span>
<form method="post" action="insert.php"> 
  <table width="442" border="0" align="center">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4" align="left" class="A9" scope="row"><span class="arial"><strong>NAME</strong></span></th>
      <td width="1">&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="5">      <span class="arial">
        <input type="text" name="staff_name" id="staff_name" />
      </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4" align="left" class="A9" scope="row"><span class="arial"><strong>ADDRESS</strong></span></th>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="5">      <span class="arial">
        <textarea name="home_address" id="home_address" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
      </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4" align="left" class="A9" scope="row"><span class="arial">CITY</span></th>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="5">        <span class="arial">
        <select name="city" id="city">
          <option value="London">London</option>
          <option value="Luton">Luton</option>
          <option value="Birmingham">Birmingham</option>
          <option value="Manchester">Manchester</option>
          <option value="Reading">Reading</option>
          <option value="Coventry">Coventry</option>
          <option value="Brighton">Brighton</option>
          <option value="Porthsmoth">Porthsmoth</option>
        </select>
      </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4" align="left" class="A9" scope="row"><span class="arial">AREA</span></th>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="5">        <span class="arial">
        <select name="area" id="area">
          <option value="City">City</option>
          <option value="North">North</option>
          <option value="South">South</option>
          <option value="West">West</option>
          <option value="East">East</option>
          <option value="North West">North West</option>
          <option value="North East">North East</option>
          <option value="South West">South West</option>
          <option value="South East">South East</option>
        </select>
      </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4" align="left" class="A9" scope="row"><span class="arial">PROFESSION</span></th>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="5">        <span class="arial">
        <select name="profession" id="profession">
          <option value="RGN">RGN</option>
          <option value="Physiotherapist">Physiotherapist</option>
          <option value="Radiographer">Radiographer</option>
          <option value="SALT">SALT</option>
          <option value="Pharmacist">Pharmacist</option>
          <option value="Doctor">Doctor</option>
          <option value="HCA">HCA</option>
          <option value="Porter">Porter</option>
        </select>
      </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4" align="left" class="A9" scope="row"><span class="arial">SPECIALITY</span></th>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="5">      <span class="arial">
        <input type="text" name="speciality" id="speciality" />
      </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4" align="left" class="A9" scope="row"><span class="arial">COMPANY</span></th>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="5">      <span class="arial">
        <input type="text" name="company" id="company" />
      </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4" align="left" class="A9" scope="row"><span class="arial">HOME TEL.</span></th>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="5">      <span class="arial">
        <input type="text" name="home_tel" id="home_tel" />
      </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4" align="left" class="A9" scope="row"><span class="arial">MOBILE</span></th>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="5">      <span class="arial">
        <input type="text" name="mobile_tel" id="mobile_tel" />
      </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4" align="left" class="A9" scope="row"><span class="arial">EMAIL</span></th>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="5">      <span class="arial">
        <input type="text" name="email_address" id="email_address" />
      </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4" align="left" class="A9" scope="row"><span class="arial">PROFESSIONAL BODY</span></th>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="5">        <span class="arial">
        <select name="pro_body" id="pro_body">
          <option value="NMC">NMC</option>
          <option value="AHP">AHP</option>
          <option value="GMC">GMC</option>
          <option value="Others">Others</option>
        </select>
      </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4" align="left" class="A9" scope="row"><span class="arial">REGISTRATION</span></th>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="5">      <span class="arial">
        <input type="text" name="reg_no" id="reg_no" />
      </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4" align="left" class="A9" scope="row"><span class="arial">EXPIERY DATE</span></th>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="5">      <span class="arial">
        <input type="text" name="exp_date" id="exp_date" />
      </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4" align="left" class="A9" scope="row"><span class="arial">PROFILE</span></th>
      <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="5" rowspan="2">      <span class="arial">
        <textarea name="profile" id="profile" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
      </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4" align="left" class="A9" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="10" align="left" class="arial" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th width="26" align="left" class="arial" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
      <th width="22" align="left" class="arial" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
      <th width="22" align="left" class="arial" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
      <th width="19" align="left" class="arial" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
      <th align="left" class="arial" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
      <th width="30" align="left" class="arial" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
      <th width="13" align="left" class="arial" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
      <th width="13" align="left" class="arial" scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
      <th width="56" align="left" class="arial" scope="row"><span class="arial">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
      </span></th>
      <th width="156" align="left" class="arial" scope="row"><span class="arial">
        <input type="reset" name="Reset" id="reset" value="Reset" />
      </span></th>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My PHP code:

```
<?php
  $host="localhost"; // Host name 
  $username=""; // Mysql username 
  $password=""; // Mysql password 
  $db_name=""; // Database name 
  $tbl_name="staff"; // Table name 

  // Connect to server and select database.
  mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
  mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

  // Get values from form 
  $staff_name=$_POST['staff_name'];
  $home_address=$_POST['home_address'];
  $city=$_POST['city'];
  $area=$_POST['area'];
  $profession=$_POST['profession'];
  $speciality=$_POST['speciality'];
  $company=$_POST['company'];
  $home_tel=$_POST['home_tel'];
  $mobile_tel=$_POST['mobile_tel'];
  $email=$_POST['email'];
  $pro_body=$_POST['pro_body'];
  $reg_no=$_POST['reg_no'];
  $exp_date=$_POST['exp_date'];
  $profile=$_POST['profile'];

  // Insert data into mysql 
  $sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(SID, staff_name, home_address, city, area, profession, speciality, company, home_tel, mobile_tel, email, pro_body, reg_no, exp_date, profile)VALUES('NUL', '$staff_name', '$home_address', '$city', '$area', '$profession', '$speciality', '$company', '$home_tel', '$mobile_tel', '$email', '$pro_body', '$reg_no', '$exp_date', '$profile')";
  $result=mysql_query($sql);

  // if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful". 
  if($result){
    echo "Successful";
    echo "<BR>";
    echo "<a href='insert.php'>Back to main page</a>";
  } else {
    echo "ERROR";
  }
?> 

<?php 
  // close connection 
  mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Interesting error. It looks like an HTML page!

Comment: Did you mean to post an error or your html code?

Comment: It seems like I'm posting this comment at least once a day, but **you should really read up on SQL injection attacks**.

Comment: Note that the first value you pass to your sql query is 'NUL' and not 'NULL'. Typically in that situation you want to simply not include that column in the query. Note, too, that you don't want to dynamically pass the table name if you already know the table and columns as you do here. Finally, you should look up PHP PDO and not use the deprecated `mysql_query` functions, which are vulnerable to security issues.

Comment: @NathanielFord It looks like the string literal `'NUL'` and not actually `NULL`.

Comment: @Ic I doubt they're trying to insert the literal 'NUL' into a column labeled 'SID', but I suppose I could be wrong. Without knowing what error they're acutally getting it's almost impossible to say.

Comment: @NathanielFord Yeah you're probably right, but I think your last sentence hits the nail on the head. There's just too many assumptions to make without knowing the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(SID, staff_name, home_address, city, area, profession, speciality, company, home_tel, mobile_tel, email, pro_body, reg_no, exp_date, profile) VALUES('NUL', '$staff_name', '$home_address', '$city', '$area', '$profession', '$speciality', '$company', '$home_tel', '$mobile_tel', '$email', '$pro_body', '$reg_no', '$exp_date', '$profile')";
```

Maybe a space before

```
VALUES
```

A good start at least;)

Comment: Make sure all those literal PHP values in that query have been escaped using `mysql_real_escape_string()` first.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments,

Answer (score 0):

For email you have name and id 'email_address' and in the insert query you are trying to fetch with

```
$email=$_POST['email']
```